# How can I uninstall older versions of .NET SDKs and runtimes with a PowerShell script?

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core, automation

In one PowerShell script, I am trying to install the latest version of .NET SDKs and runtimes then uninstall the older versions.

I am currently using 2 resources from Microsoft:

- dotnet-install.ps1
- dotnet-core-uninstall-1.2.206301

List of SDKs and runtimes:

```
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.2
  Commit:  cb5f173b96

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.25 [..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.25 [..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.12 [..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.25 [..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.12 [..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.2 [..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I try to remove these older versions by running this command:

```
dotnet-core-uninstall remove --all --runtime
```

Error Output:

```
dotnet-core-uninstall : Unhandled exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target
of an invocation.
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet-core-uninstall remove --all --runtime
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unhandled excep... an invocation.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Uninstall.Shared.Commands.UninstallCommandExec.AskItAndReturnUserAnswer(IDictionary`2 bundles,
String userResponse)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Uninstall.Shared.Commands.UninstallCommandExec.Execute(IBundleCollector bundleCollector)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Uninstall.Shared.Configs.CommandLineConfigs.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<.cctor>b__6()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Uninstall.Shared.Exceptions.ExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<HandleException>b__0()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean
wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.ModelBindingCommandHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationContext context)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<BuildInvocationChain>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseParseErrorReporting>b__21_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<<UseHelp>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<<UseVersionOption>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<<UseTypoCorrections>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseSuggestDirective>b__22_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseParseDirective>b__20_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseDebugDirective>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<RegisterWithDotnetSuggest>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<<UseExceptionHandler>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

According to Microsoft, the uninstall tool has limitations..

**On Windows, the tool can only uninstall SDKs and Runtimes that were installed using one of the following installers:**

- The .NET SDK and runtime installer.
- The Visual Studio installer in versions earlier than Visual Studio
  2019 version 16.3.

Has anyone found a workaround for this or maybe another way to uninstall these SDKs and runtimes installed by the dotnet-installer.ps1 script? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or tips. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer, but instead more of information I've found regarding the dotnet-installer script and the SDK it "installs"

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) for dotnet-installer.ps1 script

> The install scripts do not update the registry on Windows. They just
> download the zipped binaries and copy them to a folder. If you want
> registry key values to be updated, use the .NET installers.

Install directory default is %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\dotnet on Windows and /usr/share/dotnet on Linux/macOS.

> -InstallDir|--install-dir
>
> Specifies the installation path. The directory is created if it
> doesn't exist. The default value is %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\dotnet on
> Windows and /usr/share/dotnet on Linux/macOS. Binaries are placed
> directly in this directory.

Perhaps the answer is to search this folder for SDK installations and remove the folders?

However, according to this [dotnet sdk issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8841) from 2017, these "installations" are not really doing anything.  'Dotnet' does not search this path for SDKs.  Maybe this has changed, but I did not find anything saying otherwise.

> 'dotnet' does not consider versions that were installed to the user's
> AppData folder; this is by design.

It seems like the SDK installations done by the dotnet-installer.ps1 script are meant only to be used in that same session and then forgotten about!

> By default, the script adds the install location to the $PATH **for the
> current session**. Override this default behavior by specifying the
> -NoPath|--no-path argument. **The script doesn't set the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable.**

```
dotnet-install: Note that the intended use of this script is for Continuous Integration (CI) scenarios, where:
dotnet-install: - The SDK needs to be installed without user interaction and without admin rights.
dotnet-install: - The SDK installation doesn't need to persist across multiple CI runs.
dotnet-install: To set up a development environment or to run apps, use installers rather than this script. Visit https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download to get the installer.
```

Comment: Ah. I see. I will probably need to find another way to install the latest .NET SDKs and runtimes then. Thank you for the info.